# GraphQL next does not accept 'relatedToCategories'

Tags: craft3, graphql, previous-next

I'm trying to get the **next** project in the "projects" section but **with the same category**.

So because I can't do it in one query (the value of my category is in the result), I do another query with the ID of the present project and the slug of the category.

Now GraphQL seems to not like relatedToCategories in the 'next' parameters (see image)
I tried with and without an array [], but same issue.

What's going on?

[image: GraphQL error]